# kdiff3 selecting the file from remote completely

Tags: git, kdiff3

How can I choose the complete selection in kdiff3 as C (file from remote in kdiff3) instead of changing everything line by line (merge conflicts)? I just want to choose the remote file. Also what is selection A (base file), the remote file checked out locally before new changes?

Answer (score 20):

Open "Merge" menu item. It has "*Choose C Everywhere*" option, which selects the edits in remote (C) for all lines. If you just what to use the edits on remote for unresolved conflicts, then you should select "*Choose C for All Unresolved Conficts*".

[image]

Git does [3-way merge](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). A shows the file from the parent commit of B and C commits. B is the file from the branch you are in, and C is the file from the branch you are merging from.

Comment: Instead of using kdiff I would rather select conflict (in merge/conflicts window of git extensions) and use context menu items "Choose ..." (better for binary files for ex.)

Comment: Why don't I see these options on Linux? (I'm on KDiff3 v1.8.1).

Comment: There is no such option any more

Comment: Yep there used to be (on Ubuntu Bionic at least), but cannot find on apt kdiff3 for Focal

Comment: These options are not available in KDiff3 v1.8.1, however the shortcuts are still working. Ctrl+Shift+1 is Choose A Everywhere; Ctrl+Shift+2 is Choose B Everywhere.

Comment: @Frank, thanks, this helps a lot! Can you add it as a separate answer as it is hard to notice otherwise?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 ver 1.8.1 : shortcuts are broken in my installation:
- according to Settings > Configure keyboard shortcuts it seems that shortcuts are as in the previous version Ctrl+<num> to choose current diff, Shift+Ctrl+<num> to Choose everywhere
- working, however, is only Shift+Ctrl+<num> but to choose the current diff

Unfortunately, I found no discussion place for Kdiff3:
- http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/  - is dead
- https://github.com/KDE/kdiff3 - issues unavailable, but seems maintained

Comment: Just installed 1.9.2 from sources. Seems fixed, with good old merge menu.

Answer (score 5):

Supplement to @lemiorhan 's answer:

These options are not available in KDiff3 v1.8.1, however, the shortcuts are still working. Ctrl+Shift+1 is Choose A Everywhere; Ctrl+Shift+2 is Choose B Everywhere.